# What is a tabufa file?

Tags: malware

I ran across some files on a public share.  The extension is .tabufa.  There is concern this is some sort of hack.  Based on my knowledge of that business unit and some of the file names, I suspect these files have something to do with Tableau.  Most of them are like `filename.xlsm.tabufa`, but one is `filename.lnk.tabufa`.

Another likely scenario is someone did a batch rename to tack .tabufa to the end of all file names in that folder, so this may be a wild goose chase.

I have found nothing about this extension by using a search engine.

One other clue:  There is a file named how_to_back_files.html in the same folder.  The user who identified the file extension (Right, it wasn't me.  I don't have access to that folder.) verified that this file contains the ransom note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are files that have been encrypted by GlobeImposter 2.0 Ransomware. See [this](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/644166/globeimposter-ransomware-support-crypt-pscrypt-ext-back-fileshtml/) link.

Comment: Thanks, @christopher.  My CISO just verified this.

Comment: No worries @dougp.  My company's network just got hit by this, otherwise I would not have known.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not Tableau. I would be more inclined to lean on the .xlsm portion which would indicate that it is a **Macro Enabled Excel file**. I'm guessing a Macro caused/created the custom extension either on purpose or on accident.

To verify, you can change the the extension to .xml. Open with a text editor and if it is Tableau it will start with something similar to the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<!-- build 20182.18.0627.2230                               -->
<workbook original-version='10.5' source-build='2018.2.0 (20182.18.0627.2230)' 
source-platform='mac' version='18.1'
```